# how to find an image among text in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, document-layout-analysis

ok, so here is my probleme, i have a lot of jpg files, that is a text about plant and all stuff, and there is images with it that i'm not interested in, so i would like to detect them, then to fill the image with white, so text recognition that i'll make after will not detect the images. However, i'm kinda new to manipulating jpg with python and i have no clue about how do i do that. If it's unclear, feel free to ask question, and sorry for poor gramar, i'm French. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c95u3.jpg) is a good exemple of a page with image and text, where i want to get rid of the image

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

savePath = "C:/Users/33641/Downloads/stage/codes/ImgDeleted/" #path of folder where i would like to save them
def DelImg(path, imgSavePath, name):
    if not os.path.exists(imgSavePath):
        os.makedirs(imgSavePath)

    im = Image.open(path)
    #check if it contains an image
    #if so, fill it with blank


    im.save(imgSavePath+name)

path = "C:/Users/33641/Downloads/stage/codes/Cropped" #path of folder that contains images

for i in range(len(os.listdir(path))): #explore all my folder that contains images
    path2 = "C:/Users/33641/Downloads/stage/codes/Cropped/" + os.listdir(path)[i]
    for j in range(len(os.listdir(path2))): #explore all images and send them to the function
        DelImg("C:/Users/33641/Downloads/stage/codes/JPEG/" + os.listdir(path)[i]+"/"+os.listdir(path2)[j], savePath+os.listdir(path)[i], "/"+os.listdir(path2)[j])
    print(str(i)+ "/"+str(len(os.listdir(path))))
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @medium-dimensional i'm gonna try